# Where do I find Arvak's skull in the Soul Cairn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I am playing Dawnguard, the Skyrim DLC, and I have been given a quest to find Arvak's skull in the Soul Cairn. It is a big place, so can anyone lead me right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you pass through the "gate" where you met the questgiver, go EEEN (about 70 degrees right from N), it's a long walk but eventually you will find a shrine-like structure which is basically a roof supported by 4 columns, it will be illuminated from within in purple, the skull will be at the foot of a pedestal at the shrine's center. The shrine is due east of the entrance to Valerica's prison.

Here's a video guide.

Answer (score 2):

I find the Soul Cairn to be hard to navigate (which is very unusual for me).  Typically, I don't have a problem with finding Arvak... eventually.

There is, however, a mod which is available on Bethesda Net (but not on Nexus, oddly) which provides quest markers for both Arvak and the Opus.

It is available for the [PC](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3009869), [XBox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3009934), and [PS4](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3009993).

Comment: There's an argument for saying that the Soul Cairn is supposed to be hard to navigate. If you find it unusually confusing then it's doing its job: it's supposed to be like Purgatory - a vast, misty, boring expanse for souls to eternally wonder aimlessly. Even the map is useless there. It's the only part of the game I really didn't like and couldn't wait to get out of, but then maybe you're not supposed to like it.  As for Arvak, I found him by mistake, which I was rather pleased about.